# How to restore WinRE and some advanced startup options

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, uefi, bitlocker

The advanced startup options shows the "Troubleshoot" option, but inside it there is only "UEFI Firmware Settings" and "Startup Settings" (no command prompt).

I am using a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 (i5, 128GB SSD, 4 GB RAM) with drive C: with BitLocker XTS-AES 256-bit encryption (incompatible with Win7) with TPM and PIN. `reagentc /info` reveals that WinRE is disabled.

Here's what I did from the beginning when everything worked:
I went into Disk Management and shrunk my C: partition by 22 GB (I remember reading somewhere that BitLocker is fine if you shrink the partition). In the unallocated space, I created a 20 GB FAT32 partition called KALI with drive letter `L:` and a 2 GB FAT32 partition called KALISWAP with no drive letter.

Then, I booted from a freshly created Kali 2018.2 Live USB (ISOHybrid written using Rufus in DD mode) and during the installation, I used the KALI partition as Ext4 journaling file system and formatted it with ext4 filesystem with mount point `/`, and I used the KALISWAP partition as swap space and formatted it with swap filesystem. Installation went smoothly.

The next boot went into Kali Linux without asking me anything (sidenote: whenever I boot from "kali" device in the UEFI settings, it shows the GRUB menu with Windows Boot Manager as an option). I shut it down and moved "kali" to 2nd boot priority and "Windows Boot Manager" to 1st boot priority. When I tried to boot Windows, whether I enter my PIN or recovery key, it went to a "There are no more BitLocker recovery options on your PC" screen. I used Windows installation media to unlock the C: drive and booted into Windows. It showed a "Scanning and repairing \randomstuff\randomstuff..." text (attached) and then booted successfully. Since I didn't want to do that every time I restarted my PC, and since I didn't want to turn off BitLocker as I would have to later update my printed and externally stored recovery keys, I suspended BitLocker via PowerShell for the next 15 reboots (maximum value).

Then, I downloaded EasyBCD and added a Windows entry for drive L: (Linux/BSD was greyed out). It switched to the old B&W menu. Also, it didn't work because Linux isn't Windows, and so I checked the "Use Metro bootloader" checkbox and removed that entry (Probably fine, but added it here anyway).

Now it works fine, except I have to re-run that command every 15 reboots, and also when I tried to access the Command Prompt via advanced startup options, it isn't there. I tried all the other commands like `bootrec /fixmbr` and such.

I'll attach pictures/screenshots of my current DiskMgmt and UEFI screens (I don't know why there are duplicates, no USBs or external HDDs/SSDs are plugged in).

Apparently, I'm not cool enough to embed images so [click here for aforementioned image attachments](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fX-mXqO-d31L8mg0hw3jPGaBl5aFzGDh?usp=sharing).

**EDIT:** I tried `reagentc /enable` from another SE question, but even when BitLocker is suspended it says: `REAGENTC.EXE: Windows RE cannot be enabled on a volume with BitLocker Drive Encryption enabled.`

Comment: Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I have already added a Google Drive link which is set to everyone can view...